# How can I access the selected value of my partial view dropdown list from the main page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a partial view dropdown list that look like this:

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Category, Model.Categories,"Select One")
```

I call the partial view like this

```
   @Html.Action("Categories", "Attendance", new { department =departmentId })
```

When I F12 the page I see that my option list looks like this:

```
 <select id="Category" name="Category"><option value="">Select One</option>
 <option value="In class participation">Option A</option>
 <option value=" Option A "> Option A </option>
 <option value=" Option B "> Option B </option>
 <option value=" Option C "> Option C </option>
 <option value=" Option D "> Option D </option>
 </select>
```

I then write a javascript to test whether I could reach the value of the selected value like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function (e) {
    var sellected = $("#Category").valueOf();
    var selectedVal = sellected.valueOf();


    $("#save").click(function () {

        alert(sellected.toString());
            return false;

      });
       });
   </script>
```

Instead of the value I get [Object Object] in my popup.  I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010 and HTML5.  Don't know if this matter but I only had the intelisence of 'valueOf() instead of val() like I've seen in examples.  How can I access the selected value of my partial view dropdown list from the main page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
$("#save").click(function () {

    alert($("#Category").val());
        return false;

  });
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Even though val() is not in my intellisence list.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function (e) {


    $("#save").click(function () {
        var sellected = $("#Category").find(':selected');

        alert(sellected.val());
            return false;

      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Tried to do var sellected = $("#Category").find() but 'find()' is not in my intellisence list.  Neither is 'val()'.  Is there some option that must be turned on that I'm missing?

Comment: Which jQuery version you are using?